# Setting location to current in google maps in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to set the location to current location in the google maps function in angular. I have used the following code but it is not working:

page.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-find-us',
  templateUrl: './find-us.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./find-us.page.scss'],
})
export class FindUsPage implements OnInit {
  zoom = 12
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    maxZoom: 15,
    minZoom: 8,
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.center = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      }
    })
  }
}
```

the map thats displays is centred on Google HQ in USA as a default setting I believe but when I add the code above it doesn't relocate to my current location.

Any ideas would be hugely welcome, many thanks in advance

Comment: Please update the post and describe how it is not working.

Comment: oh sorry, have updated the post

Comment: I don't know much about Google maps, but I belive you need to tell the map to re-center itself.

Comment: This example uses `panTo` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#MarkerEvents

Comment: thanks for the help, I think i have identified the issue tho, geolocation is blocked when using testing on the localhost so wont run. Will have to look at other ways to test it. thanks for the help